# How to truncate RT index table in sphinx

Tags: php, sphinx

Is it possible to truncate the RT index table in sphinx.
If yes, how can we do this..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now it is available:

```
TRUNCATE RTINDEX rt;
```

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#sphinxql-truncate-rtindex

Answer (score 1):

Seems that it's available in the trunk version, but not the latest release (2.0.4)
http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=9236